# SQL Server: Differential backup done, but can't find full backup

Tags: sql-server

I noticed that my maintenance plans are doing a differential backup, but I can't locate the full backup, so I don't know from where it is doing it from. Is it possible to find out from where a DIfferential backup is getting the full backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server tracks backupsets. Perhaps this will point you in the right direction.

```
;with fullBackup
as
(
    select bs.backup_set_id, bs.checkpoint_lsn, bs.database_name, bs.type, bmf.physical_device_name, bs.backup_start_date, bs.backup_finish_date
    from msdb..backupset bs
        inner join msdb..backupmediaset fms on bs.media_set_id = fms.media_set_id
        inner join msdb..backupmediafamily bmf on fms.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
    where bs.type = 'D' --FULL
)


SELECT 
     bs.database_name
     , bs.type
     , bmf.physical_device_name AS DiffPath
     , bs.backup_start_date as DiffStart
     , bs.backup_finish_date as DiffEnd
     , fb.physical_device_name as FullPath
     , fb.backup_start_date as FullStart
     , fb.backup_finish_date as FullEnd
from msdb..backupset bs
        inner join msdb..backupmediafamily bmf on bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
        left join fullBackup fb on bs.database_backup_lsn = fb.checkpoint_lsn --and bs.database_name = fb.database_name
WHERE bs.type = 'I' --DIFF
```

Comment: We just had a server crash and found some backup files and some differential files. would it be possible to find out where those differential files got the full backup from without SQL Server?

Comment: If you attempt to use the restore wizard in SSMS, you should be able to select all of the files you found. at that point, The wizard should be able to associate the backup files in to each other (if any of them relate).  You can use the timeline feature to get a more granular restore point if needed. If you need further assistance, i'd recommend creating a new question.